# Left Side Navigation crumples in IE7 only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, navigation

Ok! So I made this nav bar and it works perfectly in all browsers except IE7.
It is a left side nav and for some reason it collapses in IE7 but every other browser displays it fine.

Here's the html.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html> 
    <head>
       <title>Test</title>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head> 
    <body>
<ul class="navbar">
    <li class="nav_head"><div class="navhd_outline"><a href="/admin/products/">Products</a></div></li>
        <ul>
            <li class="nav_subhead"><div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">View Categories</a></div></li>
            <li class="nav_subhead"><div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">Add/Remove</a></div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_head"><div class="navhd_outline"><a href="/admin/email/">Email</a></div></li>
        <ul>
            <li class="nav_subhead"><div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">New Blast</a></div></li>
            <li class="nav_subhead"><div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">View Blast</a></div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_head"><div class="navhd_outline"><a href="/admin/reports/">Reports</a></div></li>
        <ul>
            <li class="nav_subhead"><div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">By Month</a></div></li>
            <li class="nav_subhead"><div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">By Type</a></div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_head"><div class="navhd_outline"><a href="/admin/recipes/">Recipes</a></div></li>
        <ul>
            <li class="nav_subhead"><div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">View Recipes</a></div></li>
            <li class="nav_subhead"><div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">Add/Remove</a></div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_head"><div class="navhd_outline"><a href="/admin/television/">Television</a></div></li>
        <ul>
            <li class="nav_subhead"><div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">View List</a></div></li>
            <li class="nav_subhead"><div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">Add/Remove</a></div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_head blog_head"><div class="navhd_outline"><a href="/admin/blog/">Blog</a></div></li>
        <ul>
            <li class="nav_subhead"><div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">View Posts</a></div></li>
            <li class="nav_subhead"><div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">Add/Remove</a></div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_bottom">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is the CSS.

```css
.navbar {
    float: left;
    background-color: #4d89d1;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 18px 0px;
    top: -25px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.nav_head {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1px;
    height: 36px;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav_head a {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #900606;
}

.nav_head a:hover {
    color: #f5bf2b;
}

.navhd_outline {
    margin: 1px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    border: 1px dashed #f5bf2b;
    width: 154px;
    height: 2px;
}

.nav_subhead {
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #900606;
    height: 36px;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 155px;
    text-align: right;
}

.nav_subhead a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.nav_subhead a:hover {
    color: #f5bf2b;
}

.navsub_outline {
    margin: 1px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px dashed #f5bf2b;
    width: 131px;
    height: 2px;
}

.nav_bottom {
    height: 30px;
    background-position: 33px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: So I found one error but it still didn't fix the issue.  I have an extra </li> in the first level of li's.  If I remove the first instance, everything falls apart.  If I remove the second instance, all other browsers work but I still have the IE7 issue.

Comment: As you know, you have very invalid HTML.  If fixing the invalid HTML causes other problems, then you have to fix those too, **not** go back to the invalid HTML.  Bad HTML causes browsers to render things unpredictably (again, as you can see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have invalid HTML.  The problem repeats through every single `<li>` so I'm only showing the first one...

```
<ul class="navbar">

    <li class="nav_head">
        <div class="navhd_outline"><a href="/admin/products/">Products</a></div>
    </li>  <!-- <<< this one closes the LI item -->
        <ul>
            <li class="nav_subhead">
                  <div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">View Categories</a></div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav_subhead">
                  <div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">Add/Remove</a></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>  <!-- <<< this is presently an extra one outside of the LI item -->

    ...
    <li class="nav_bottom">&nbsp;</li>

</ul>
```

You still have an extra closing `</li>` tag for every single `<li>` item.  The inner `<ul>` needs to be contained *inside* the `<li></li>`, where you have it *outside* along with another `</li>`.  Remove `</li>` tags as indicated below...

```
<ul class="navbar">

    <li class="nav_head">
        <div class="navhd_outline"><a href="/admin/products/">Products</a></div>
        <ul>  <!-- <<< the entire child UL is inside the LI where it belongs -->
            <li class="nav_subhead">
                  <div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">View Categories</a></div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav_subhead">
                  <div class="navsub_outline"><a href="#">Add/Remove</a></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>  <!-- <<< this one closes the LI item -->

    ...
    <li class="nav_bottom">&nbsp;</li>

</ul>
```

Run your page through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: I noted this on my comment. It falls apart completely when i put the </li>  after the contained <ul>. I can attempt to fix it and that makes sense as it does validate. But it works in every browser except IE7 with the </li> before the inner <ul>.

Comment: @user1329415, That's because every browser _tries_ to overcome invalid HTML in their own way (they just guess at what you intended).  What you don't see are all the tags the browser is inserting into the DOM to overcome your errors.  You need to _start_ with valid HTML and build from there.

Comment: In other words, you're building on mud instead of concrete... sooner or later, it all falls apart.

Comment: Ok. I got it to validate properly. And with the proper doctype it at least doesn't get totally screwed up. Thank you.

Comment: @user1329415, You're welcome.  Yes, IE is very fussy about `doctype` too.  Please don't forget to "accept" my answer by clicking the check-mark, earning some rep for both of us.